# Django template decoupling : cant access to the static files outside of Django project

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

My app is decoupled between APIs and templates. I want to know the way to communicate the APIs to templates.

I know I can pull all the static files into API repo by `python manage.py collectstatic` , but I dont want to couple APIs and templates together into one folder.

I am trying to access the static files from my django app to the static files that are outside of my django app. I want to access the files in UIUX/static to DjangoRepo/myapp/static. it looks like below

```
UIUX/
 - static
  - staticfile...
 - templates
  - index.html
DjangoRepo/
 - myapp
  - static
  - templates
```

my view.py

```
class IndexViewTemplateView(View):
    # trying to acess the inedx.html file that is outside of Django file
    template_name = '../../../UIUX/templates/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

I did not edit my template at all for this.
is there any other template setting I need to do to archive this ?

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')],
        # 'DIRS':[],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            # 'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line 
from - 'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')],
to - 'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'templates'),os.path.join('C:/Users/kevin/workspace/UIUX/static')].

Comment: The os.path module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths. join - joins one or more path components. Using this we can call Local directory files.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know your PROJECT_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS.

Comment: PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    #os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/'),
    "C:/Users/kevin/workspace/UIUX/static",
)

Comment: You want get files in templates or static?

Comment: Both. I want to get the access to the templates that has the access to the static files

Comment: With static file you can use "python manage.py collectstatic". With templates directory you can hard path it. Try it.

Comment: right, I know I can. But I want to decouple the APIs from UIUX